# tcl - explanation on the following regexp and regsub commands

Tags: regex, tcl

Ok so tcl expert here (Brad Lanam) wrote the following **regexp** and **regsub** commands in a tcl script to parse my file format (called liberty (.lib) used in chip design). I just want to know what they mean (if not why they were used since you don't have the context). I have used the references on tcl wiki but simply cannot seem to connect the dots. Here's the snippet of his code

```
set fh [open z.lib r]
set inval false
while { [gets $fh line] >= 0 } {
  if { [regexp {\);} $line] } {
    set inval false
  }
  if { [regexp {index_(\d+)} $line all idx] } {
    regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
    regsub {".*} $d {} d
    regsub -all {,} $d {} d
    dict set risedata constraints indexes $idx $d
  }
  if { $inval } {
    regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
    regsub {".*} $d {} d
    regsub -all {[ ,]+} $d { } d
    set row [expr {$rcount % 5}]
    set column [expr {$rcount / 5}]
    set i 0
    foreach {v} [split $d { }] {
      set c [lindex [dict get $risedata constraints indexes 3] $i]
      dict set risedata constraints constraint $c $row $column $v
      incr i
    }
    incr rcount
  }
  if { [regexp {values} $line] } {
    set inval true
    set row 0
    set rcount 0
  }
}
close $fh
```

Especially, what does

```
if { [regexp {index_(\d+)} $line all idx] } {
        regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
        regsub {".*} $d {} d
        regsub -all {,} $d {} d
```

Mean?? does line containing \d+ search for line variable for more than one digit and match against the string line ? What is `regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d` ?

Big thanks for helping a noob like me understand.

Reference: Brad Lanam

Comment: Do you only need an explanation for the regex patterns themselves, or the entire code?

Comment: @CAustin I need help in understanding the regexp and regsub patterns. What do the characters mean when used in conjunction ( example: regsub {".*} $d {} d) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take it line-by-line and explain what it appears to be doing.

```
if { [regexp {index_(\d+)} $line all idx] } {
```

This first line checks to see if the string stored in `line` includes
a substring of `index_` followed by 1 or more digits.  If so, it
stores the matching substring in `all` (which the rest of the code
appears to ignore) and stores the digits found in the variable `idx`.

So if `line` were set to `"stuff index_123 more stuff"`, you would end
up with `all` set to `index_123` and `idx` set to `123`.

```
regsub {^[^"]*"} $line {} d
```

This `regsub` will remove everything from the beginning of `line` up
to and including the first double-quote.  It stores the result in `d`.

```
regsub {".*} $d {} d
```

The next `regsub` operates on the value now in `d`.  It looks for a
double-quote and removes that character and everything afterward,
storing the result again in `d`.

```
regsub -all {,} $d {} d
```

Finally, this line deletes any commas found in `d`, storing the result
back in `d`.

The next set of `regexp`/`regsub` lines perform a similar set of
operations except for the last line in the group:

```
regsub -all {[ ,]+} $d { } d
```

After the previous lines removed everything except the section that
had been in double-quotes, this line removes any sections made up of
one or more spaces and commas and substitutes them with a single
space.

Let me know if that is clear.